# React Native Expo.Font.loadAsync doesn't load Material Icons

Tags: react-native, expo

I have a React Native, React hybrid app. For React Native i am using react-native-elements.

My app is run using Expo and was built out with the react-native init. I am getting the Material Icons (missing) RSD;

[image: Material Icons missing]

Through much searching, i have found the @expo/vector-icons but it doesn't seem to work. My App.js looks like this;

```
import React from 'react'
import { Font, AppLoading } from 'expo'
import { MaterialIcons } from '@expo/vector-icons'
import HybridApp from './src/App'

export default class NativeApp extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      fontsAreLoaded: false
    }
  }
  async componentWillMount() {
    await Font.loadAsync(MaterialIcons.font)
    this.setState({ fontsAreLoaded: true })
  }
  render() {
    const { fontsAreLoaded } = this.state
    return !fontsAreLoaded ? <AppLoading /> : <HybridApp />
  }
}
```

As you can see, i am waiting for the font to load... all to no avail.

Comment: In your `app.json` you don't happen to have 'json' included in your `app.packagerOpts.assetExts: []` do you? If so then yeah, `@expo/vector-icons` won't work properly 

Comment: see the complete answer here: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54094846/react-native-async-font-loading/61391572#61391572)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

After hours wracking my brain on this, the answer was there in front of me the whole time.

Presumably, React Native Elements refers to Material icons as `Material Icons`, *not* `MaterialIcons`.

This means that the default import from `@expo/vector-icons` does not work as their reference to Material icons is different.

The solution is to manually select Material icons from expo, replacing this line;

```
await Font.loadAsync(MaterialIcons.font)
```

with

```
await Font.loadAsync({
  'Material Icons': require('@expo/vector-icons/fonts/MaterialIcons.ttf')
})
```

I hope this saves someone some time in the future.

Comment: I guess it became MaterialIcons now, but thanks for the answer.

Comment: Got a reference as to where this change should be made??

Answer (score 1):

This question is old, but what worked for me and quite straightforward is

```
import { Ionicons } from "@expo/vector-icons";
await Font.loadAsync({...Ionicons.font, ...other imports })
```

Answer (score 0):

The icons are actually fonts and must first be loaded.  It seems they are autoloaded sometimes and others times are not.

So to ensure they are loaded, do this:

```
        import FontAwesome from './node_modules/@expo/vector-icons/fonts/FontAwesome.ttf';
        import MaterialIcons from './node_modules/@expo/vector-icons/fonts/MaterialIcons.ttf';
    ... 
      async componentWillMount() {
        try {
          await Font.loadAsync({
            FontAwesome,
            MaterialIcons
          });

          this.setState({ fontLoaded: true });
        } catch (error) {
          console.log('error loading icon fonts', error);
        }
      }
...
  render() {

    if (!this.state.fontLoaded) {

      return <AppLoading />;

    }
```

Then when you reference the type, it must be the same type that the component you are using is expecting.

For example, react native elements expects these types: material-community, font-awesome, octicon, ionicon, foundation, evilicon, simple-line-icon, zocial, or entypo

See complete answer here:
http://javascriptrambling.blogspot.com/2018/03/expo-icon-fonts-with-react-native-and.html

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have any dependency warnings when you run the app. I had an expo-font version warning, when I fixed it this error went away.

```
Some dependencies are incompatible with the installed expo package version:
 - expo-font - expected version range: ~8.4.0 - actual version installed: ^9.1.0
```